# Problem in getting inserted record`s ID Using transaction with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, oracle-manageddataaccess

In a `.Net framework` project I added a `EF 6.x DbContext Generator` using visual studio that adds an `.edmx` file with some `.tt` files in it; that implements my `database first` structure.

Then I connected to my `oracle` database and added my tables into it with some models like this:

```
// DatabaseContext.tt > USER_TYPE.cs
public class USER_TYPE
{
    public int ID { get; set; } // have sequence and insert trigger.
    public string NAME { get; set; }
}

// DatabaseContext.tt > USER.cs
public class USER
{
    public int ID { get; set; } // have sequence and insert trigger.
    public int USER_TYPE_ID { get; set; } // foreign key to USER_TYPES.ID
    public string NAME { get; set; }
}
```

**Also** `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework` Nuget package is installed.

Both tables have `ID` as primary key with `trigger` and `sequence` that will give the `ID` column, a unique value.

Now I want to begin a transaction to insert some records in the tables that are related together:

```
using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
using (var transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    // insert userType
    var userType = new USER_TYPE
    {
        NAME = "admin"
    };

    db.USER_TYPES.Add(userType);
    db.SaveChanges();

    // userType.ID == 0 : true

    // insert user
    var user = new USER
    {
        NAME = "admin user",
        USER_TYPE_ID = userType.ID
    };

    db.USERS.Add(user);
    db.SaveChanges();

    transaction.Commit(); 
}
```

The problem is after `db.USER_TYPES.Add(userType); db.SaveChanges()` we know the `userType.ID` will remains `0` (because we are using oracle).

There is some solutions in the web that suggest to get the latest inserted ID by executing a select max ID query or get next sequence value before insert. but when we use **Transaction**, there is no actual record in db to select max, or selecting from the sequence is not accurate and is vague.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to configure your EF model to tell it that the database is generating that value, and then it will query it after insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [David Browne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7297700/david-browne-microsoft)'s comment in the first post and using [this](https://github.com/AITGmbH/AIT.EF.Oracle.IdentityPatch) Nuget package, I simply changed the **StoredGeneratedPattern** to `Identity` of my **primary key column** in my `.edmx` file.

By this change, the Entity Framework will not pass the ID in the insert sql script to the database:

```
insert into MY_TABLE (NAME) VALUES (@some_value) -- ID is not passed.
```

And also after insertion, the ID (I mean primary key column) will be obtained automatically from the database, even if I use `transactions`.

```
using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
using (var transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    var userType = new USER_TYPE
    {
        NAME = "admin"
    };

    db.USER_TYPES.Add(userType);
    db.SaveChanges();

    Debug.Assert.IsTrue(userType.ID != 0); // ✔️ will be passed.
}
```